# How do I make only one page landscape in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

Changing Page Layout to Landscape changes my whole document. I want to insert a single Landscape page into my Word document. How do I make only one page landscape in Word 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add some text to the page you want to change to Landscape.
2. Select this text.
3. Go to the Layout tab and click the arrow on the bottom right corner of the Page Setup section of the ribbon. This opens the Page Setup dialog box. Confirm that you're on the Margins tab.
4. Below Orientation, choose “Landscape.”
5. Then at the bottom, **click the Apply To drop-down box and choose “Selected Text.”** Click “OK.”

Comment: You missed the step of actually selecting the text of the area you want to make landscape. Also note that this will also insert section breaks in the document and all that they entail https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-section-breaks-to-change-the-layout-or-formatting-in-one-section-of-your-document-4cdfa638-3ea9-434a-8034-bf1e4274c450. You can achieve these same yourself by inserting section breaks before and after the area you wish to change and changing orientation without this dialog. (Just an alternative)

Comment: Many thanks indeed @Mokubai! Answer updated with the missing step. Thank you for your alternative suggestion, too!